# How to create a new column filtering data by date

Tags: r, datefilter

I need to sort my data by date. Previously I had one dataset and used select and filter to create two separate datasets, one with data from June 30 or earlier and the other with data from July 1 or later. However, my problem is that I seem to have lost some rows during this process - I went from 1390 rows in my original dataset to 1335 rows between the two new datasets. I can't figure out what happened.

What I am trying to do now is use my original dataset, ethica_surveys and create a new column. I want to call this column pre_post. I know how to create a new column, but I want to filter the data into this column based on my date parameters. So the rows containing pre should be dated June 30 or earlier, and those containing post should be dated July 1 or later. I am filtering based on the variable response_time, but I am just unsure of how to code this in RStudio.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: How does this question not violate SO rules re Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work after a lot of trial and error.

```
ethica_surveys$pre_post <- 
    if_else(ethica_surveys$response_time > as.Date("2018-07- 
    01"),"post","pre")
```